# What is the best way to search for a string in a list of list of strings c#

Tags: c#, list, search

What is the best way to search for a string in a list of lists of strings?
Example I have many lists of strings e.g. List1  List 2 etc. and all of the lists are collected in a List of Lists (e.g. ListofLists<,...>.
Now I want to search for the string "foo" in the list of lists. Is there a way to optimize this in c#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just want to know if one of the lists contains the string?

Comment: What is "best"? Compact syntax or fastest search?

Comment: Sorry my question is not clear enough, I mean fastest for a large(ish) dataset. SImilar to tries for a list of strings but something I can use for a list of lists

Comment: Consider using `HashSet` instead of `List`. Try to use `BinarySearch` (need to sort first; binary search is fast but sorting is slow.). Also see [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Answer (score 1):

**Using Linq:**

To check if any of the lists contains the string 'foo':

```
collection.Any(x => x.Contains("foo"));
```

To get the particular list which contains the string 'foo':

```
collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("foo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
var listOfLists = new List<List<string>>();

// insert code to populate listOfLists

var containsFoo = listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x).Any(x => x == "foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just summarize/optimize other answers:

The best way to do this is using LINQ. Therefore you could use two ways:

1. You could flaten the list and look wether it contains an element
2. You could check all lists wether one list contains the element

**Flaten the list**

This is done with `SelectMany`:

```
listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x).Contains("foo");
```

`SelectMany` combines all elements of the sublists and sublists of the sublists (and so on) into one list, so you can check all items, wether one contains the string (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Check all lists**

This is done with `Any`:

```
listOfLists.Any(x => x.Contains("foo"));
```

`Any` checks wether any item fulfills the condition (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx).

Actually it seems to be more efficient to check all lists (With a randomly generated list with a total of 10,000 entries the first possibility needs averragely 34ms and the second one 31).

---

In both possibilities I use `Contains`, which simply checks, wether the list contains the element (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Of course you could still use a loop as well:

```
var contains = false;
foreach (var l in listOfLists)
    foreach (var i in l)
        if (i == "foo")
        {
            contains = true;
            goto end;
        }
end:
```

But this is less readable, less effective, more complicated and less elegant.

However, if you don't just want to check, wether it exists, but do a bit more with it, the last possibility is possibly the easiest one. If you want an optimized version for another case, feel free to specify your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe my question was not clear enough, but I am wondering how to make the search as fast as possible for a large dataset (large-ish 10000 -100000 records) when it is a list of lists. At first I was thinking to use a trie structure, so I guess my question is if there is a similar way to optimize the search for a list of lists

Comment: I'd probably use a database for this - I don't know, wether there's a faster way than those I pointed out for doing this. I'll run a profiler anyway to give you information on what way's faster.